# Working with abstract / generic class in spring boot rest - crud api

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

im really struggling with my problem right now. I'm trying to solve this issue for quit long and maybe I get help here.

I do have a simple Spring Boot CRUD Project connected with my MySQL Database (localhost:3306) and everything works fine. The moment I modify my classes to a more common oop structure I get several errors and nothing works anymore.

Simple sketch of my structure:

- Employee (abstract) class

  - Clerk (Entity) class
  - Admin (Entity) class

The employee class contains only one field (employee id "emp_id") and I want to spare me the retyping of the jpaRepo functions like finall and so on.

These are my abstract class:

```
package dev.cherry.emp.Employee.Util;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@MappedSuperclass
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public abstract class Employee {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "emp_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long empId;
}
```

This is my Repository for the abstract class:

```
package dev.cherry.emp.Repository;

import dev.cherry.emp.Employee.Util.Employee;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean;

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {
}
```

This is the Service Class for my Abstract class. Generics are included to reuse finall for clerk and admin class:

```
package dev.cherry.emp.Service;

import dev.cherry.emp.Repository.EmployeeRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class EmployeeService<T> {

    private final EmployeeRepository employeeRepo;

    @Autowired
    public EmployeeService(EmployeeRepository employeeRepo) {
        this.employeeRepo = employeeRepo;
    }

    public List<T> allEmps() {
        return (List<T>) employeeRepo.findAll();
    }
}
```

And this is my Controller Class for the abstract class Employee:

```
package dev.cherry.emp.Controller;

import dev.cherry.emp.Service.EmployeeService;
import org.apache.coyote.Response;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class EmployeeController<T> {

    private final EmployeeService employeeService;

    @Autowired
    public EmployeeController(EmployeeService employeeService) {
        this.employeeService = employeeService;
    }

    public ResponseEntity<List<T>> allEmps() {
        List<T> allEmps = employeeService.allEmps();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(allEmps, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

I'm sorry for this boilerplate looking code. Last but not least my folderstructure, root is src/main/java/dev.cherry.emp/

```
.
├── Controller
│   ├── AdminController.java
│   ├── ClerkController.java
│   └── EmployeeController.java
├── EmpApplication.java
├── Employee
│   └── Util
│       ├── Employee.java
│       └── Gender.java
├── Model
│   ├── Admin.java
│   └── Clerk.java
├── Repository
│   ├── AdminRepository.java
│   ├── ClerkRepository.java
│   └── EmployeeRepository.java
└── Service
    ├── AdminService.java
    ├── ClerkService.java
    └── EmployeeService.java
```

And this is the error from spring boot on console:

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in dev.cherry.emp.Service.EmployeeService required a single bean, but 2 were found:
- adminRepository: defined in dev.cherry.emp.Repository.AdminRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration
- clerkRepository: defined in dev.cherry.emp.Repository.ClerkRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration

Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed

Comment: "Spare me the retyping" is *NOT* valid reason for choosing an abstract class or a template class :(  "Code reuse" and "better modularity" *ARE* two good reasons.

Comment: Of course. Maybe the wording wasn’t well chosen. I just want to build one or several functions with the same purpose, so I can reuse them in parallel for my different employee types.

Answer (score 0):

somehow I could figure out how to solve my issue. Long story short, I´ll diplaying all my classes. Short disclaimer. ChatGPT helped me to solve the issue.

My Class/Project structure:

Path: src/main/java/dev/cherry/emp

Tree from folder “emp”:

```
.
├── EmpApplication.java
└── Employee
    ├── Controller
    │   └── EmployeeController.java
    ├── Model
    │   ├── Admin.java
    │   └── Clerk.java
    ├── Repository
    │   ├── AdminRepository.java
    │   ├── ClerkRepository.java
    │   └── EmployeeRepository.java
    ├── Service
    │   └── EmployeeService.java
    └── Util
        ├── Employee.java (abstract)
        └── Gender.java (Enum)
```

Here are the classes 1-by-1. Sorry for the wall of text:

**Abstract Class Employee**

```
package dev.cherry.emp.Employee.Util;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@MappedSuperclass
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public abstract class Employee {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "emp_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long empId;
}
```

**Class Admin and Clerk (Sub-/Childclasses)**

```
package dev.cherry.emp.Employee.Model;

import dev.cherry.emp.Employee.Util.Employee;
import dev.cherry.emp.Employee.Util.Gender;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Clerk extends Employee implements Serializable{

// Attributes
}
```

---

```
package dev.cherry.emp.Employee.Model;

import dev.cherry.emp.Employee.Util.Employee;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "admin")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Component
public class Admin extends Employee implements Serializable {

// Attributes
}
```

**My Repository Classes**

```
package dev.cherry.emp.Employee.Repository;

import dev.cherry.emp.Employee.Util.Employee;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean;

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface EmployeeRepository<T extends Employee> extends JpaRepository<T, Long> {
}
```

---

```
package dev.cherry.emp.Employee.Repository;

import dev.cherry.emp.Employee.Model.Clerk;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface ClerkRepository extends EmployeeRepository<Clerk>{
}
```

---

```
package dev.cherry.emp.Employee.Repository;

import dev.cherry.emp.Employee.Model.Admin;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface AdminRepository extends EmployeeRepository<Admin> {
}
```

**My Service Class**

```
package dev.cherry.emp.Employee.Service;

import dev.cherry.emp.Employee.Util.Employee;
import dev.cherry.emp.Employee.Model.Admin;
import dev.cherry.emp.Employee.Model.Clerk;
import dev.cherry.emp.Employee.Repository.AdminRepository;
import dev.cherry.emp.Employee.Repository.ClerkRepository;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class EmployeeService {
    private final AdminRepository adminRepo;
    private final ClerkRepository clerkRepo;

    public List<? extends Employee> getAllEmps(@NotNull String type) {
        if (type.equals("Clerk")) {
            return (List<Clerk>) clerkRepo.findAll();
        } else if (type.equals("Admin")) {
            return (List<Admin>) adminRepo.findAll();
        } else throw new IllegalArgumentException("Class: " + type + " not found in project");
    }

    public Employee createEmployee(Employee employee) {
        if (employee instanceof Clerk) {
            return clerkRepo.save((Clerk) employee);
        } else if (employee instanceof Admin) {
            return adminRepo.save((Admin) employee);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Employee subclass: " + employee.getClass().getSimpleName());
        }
    }

}
```

**My Controller Class**

```
package dev.cherry.emp.Employee.Controller;

import dev.cherry.emp.Employee.Util.Employee;
import dev.cherry.emp.Employee.Service.EmployeeService;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/employees")
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class EmployeeController {

    private final EmployeeService employeeService;

    @GetMapping(value = "type/{type}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<? extends Employee>> getAllEmps(@PathVariable String type) {
        List<? extends Employee> employees = employeeService.getAllEmps(type);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(employees, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping("/new")
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> createEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
        Employee savedEmployee = employeeService.createEmployee(employee);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(savedEmployee, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

My Code works actually and on postman I could test my requests. Please feel free to show me a better way if you think it could be done smarter or with less lines of code.

Thank your very much for your support.[image: Test in Postman]